# How to append JSON objects to a json file created by multiple threads in JAVA?

Tags: java, json, writefile

I am having a method that returns json object. I am calling this method in multithreaded way. Now I want output (JSON Object) from each thread to be written in a single json file.
Is there any thread safe way to do this task.

Since multiple threads are trying to write in a single file it is failing.

Comment: If the threads finished their job, you could `join()` them.

Comment: Make the method that writes `synchronized`.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use a journaling technique.**

[image]